# Why on Xcode console I have to print object twice to print it correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, console

Suppose that I set up the breakpoint at some point of my code. I run the compiler, and app stop exactly there where i set up the breakpoint. Now I need to print object in console using, for instance:

`po messageIdentifier`

But instead of correct object i get a lot of errors:

```
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'Module-Name' from AST context:

    ...

A fatal parse error has occurred. 
LLDB may become unstable; please restart your debug session as soon as possible.
```

but when i try to tap `po messageIdentifier` second time, the I get correct answer:

`"44540ef4-7343-4cd6-89a2-a4ea97048d6f"`

Why do I have to do this twice?

Comment: [appears to be an xcode bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26769995/988769)

Comment: This problem was fixed in Xcode 7 and more